# How to push label in stack in a relocatable shared library which its objects should be compiled with -fPIC?

Tags: assembly, shared-libraries, x86-64

I am making a relocatable shared library (all compiles should be with -fPIC and -DPIC) using several object files assembled from assembly code.

In my codes I have `push label` instructions. When I assemble my assembly code down to an object file using `-fPIC -DPIC` everything looks fine, however when I want to make the shared library using the object files I get the `relocation R_X86_64_32S against '.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC` message.

I am sure the problem is with these `push label` instructions as when I remove them the error vanishes.

Any idea on how can I get it assembled?

By the way my platform is Linux with Intel x86_64 architecture and the compiler is `gcc` with GAS syntax. I am interested in 64bit libraries.

Comment: Note that assembly is assembled, not compiled.  Getting this wrong can be confusing to readers.

Comment: You should update your question with the name of the assembler you're using as `push label` has two different interpretations depending on the assembler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using GAS:

```
lea  label(%rip), %rax
push %rax
```

There's no push effective address instruction so you need to go through a register.

Note that isn't a lot of reason to use the push immediate instruction in 64-bit x86 code as arguments aren't normally passed on the stack, there may be better ways to rewrite your code.

Comment: Well then yeah I think probably I need a register somehow. I know it is not a well written code. Actually I am hardening assembly code so it is all hacking and not a well documented assembly programming. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
push label
```

use

```
lea rax,[rel label]
push rax
```

This avoids an absolute reference to `label`, replacing it with a relative reference which can be resolved in position independent code if `label` is defined in the same shared object.  The exact syntax depends on your assembler, this syntax should work on nasm at least.

Comment: Well thank you. Unfortunately I want the address to be pushed to the stack not a relative address.

Comment: @masec The actual address is pushed on the stack.  The effect of `lea rax,[rel label]` is to translate a relative address in the instruction stream into an absolute address in `rax`.

Comment: @masec: go read up on how RIP-relative addressing works.  [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058101).  RIP-relative LEA is the best way to get addresses of static locations into registers in x86-64, unless you're making position-dependent executables so you can use `mov r32, imm32`.  And like Ross said, are you sure you should be pushing the address?  Only if you've already put 6 integer/pointer args into registers rdi..r9 does the x86-64 System V ABI pass integers on the stack.